# Как убрать вспылитие?

Tags: javascript

Есть два элемента

```
  <div id="1" onclick="handlerOut()">
     <div id="2 onclick ="handlerIn()"></div>
  </div>
```

Как сделать, что-бы, когда пользователь вызывает `handlerIn()` не вызывался `handlerOut()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` или, если подключен `jquery`, то можно `return false`, он в том числе прекращает всплытие события

Answer (score 0):

Да. В функции `handleOut()` прописать `event.stopPropagation()` ( `event` - это ссылка на объект `event`, возможно у тебя у тебя другая переменная). Дело в том, что без этого происходит всплыв события и затрагиваются все внутренние контейнеры. А `stopPropagation` запрещает всплытие.